# Provide a YouTube videobar on my website

Tags: video, youtube, embed

I want to embed a videobar (see image below) on my website. The video bar is for a playlist. I have come across a few articles outlining how to do this ([such as this](http://www.tendenci.com/help-files/adding-an-embedded-youtube-video-bar-to-your-website/) [or this](http://everything.typepad.com/blog/2011/03/embedding-youtube-video-bar.html))
but all point to a page that redirects to Google http://www.google.com/uds/solutions/wizards/videobar.html

Is there any way to embed a videobar for a YouTube playlist without this Google site which is no longer available

[image]

Comment: Apparently one can not access that page you mentioned!

Comment: This site should get you going: http://12starsmedia.com/blog/how-to-embed-a-youtube-playlist-on-your-blog-or-webpage

Comment: @MohamedAnisDahmani I know...that's the problem I'm coming across...that it redirects to Google!

Comment: @skibulk thanks...close, but this only shows how to display 1 video...I want to show the whole bar.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is no longer supported officially by Googe. The only way I could see this being possible would not be as a video bar per-say but as a page with a grid of video images embedded from Youtube and when you click on the video it takes you to the video page to be able to watch the video.